# Drupal 7 Multistep forms - Remove save & preview button until last step

Tags: drupal-7

I have made a multistep/page form in Drupal (the field type is a multipage group, with multipages nested).

The form is 6 pages, and there is required info on every page. The problem is, Drupal puts a "Save" and "Preview" button on the bottom of every page of the form. Really, you CANNOT preview the form or save it until all required fields are filled out. So when users are going through the form and they hit "save" halfway through or "preview" halfway through, they get a ton of errors.

Is there any way to remove the "save" and "preview" buttons until they are on the last page (i.e. page 6 only)?

Thanks.

EDIT: I am using Field Groups to build my form by the way.

Comment: Also, I know there's a module "Multistep" but it works in D6, it is not robust enough for D7. The patches make it so the form gets "submitted" each time you hit next, therefore sending premature emails and publishing the form earlier than expected.

Comment: I have also tried the form ajaxify module (https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group_ajaxified_multipage) with the latest patch and it still seems to have a lot of errors (ajax errors going next and previous, and doesn't validate non-text fields successfully...)

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any module I found to do this, not in it's entirety anyway.

We ended up removing the preview button completely with CSS, and installing a module ([Required For Publishing](https://www.drupal.org/project/required_for_pub)) that allows you to specify "Fields Required for Publish" vs fields required to save a draft. Now there's only 3 fields to save a draft for later, but 20+ fields required to publish the event/form.

We used javascript in the multipage.js form to validate on each step so they can't move on without filling out the actual required fields on each page.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to make your own module and use hook_form_alter .. https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7 .. and check which step you are currently on .. and then remove the buttons if you are not on the last step .. and enjoy.

Something like .. unset($form['actions']['preview']);